# Secure in Playframework

Tags: security, playframework

I'm trying to install secure module in playframework, I tried with http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.2/secure but Secure.class isn't found

```
 import models.Task;
 import play.mvc.Controller;
 import play.mvc.With;

 public class Application extends Controller {

     @With(Secure.class)
     public static void index() {
```

Please any help please

Comment: Do you actually read the documentation before posting here?

Comment: @Zenklys This is actually not documented very well.  You have to eclipsify, netbeansify, etc after your do a play deps.  I was pulling my hair out for a while when I first started using Play.

Comment: I don't agree. The documentation is actually one of the best available for an existing framework. Plus Javier is a known poster of the play section. And he hasn't accepted a single answer for the moment.

Comment: Agree, no feedback, no acceptance.

Answer (score 3):

You have to add the module in the conf/dependencies.yml

It should look lie that :

```
# Application dependencies

require:
    - play
    - secure
```

Then you have to type the following command

```
play dependencies your_play_app
```

Answer (score 3):

I have the following in dependencies.yml:

```
require:
- play -> secure
```

And I believe you have to protect the whole controller, using @With(Secure.class) before the class definition:

```
@With(Secure.class)
public class Application extends Controller {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Just curious: do you know what the difference is between your answer and the answer @Yoann posted?  You have "secure" on the same line as "play", while Yoann has it on a different line.  Is the end result the same or is there a difference?  Thanks.

Comment: According to play [documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2/dependency), in this case seems to be equivalent. We only have to use the -> for including dependencies of other companies, so I believe Yoann's syntax is better.

Comment: Interesting, Play uses Maven under the covers for dep management.

Answer (score 3):

As above, and if you're using Eclipse make sure you run `play eclipsify` to bring the Secure module (and it's classes) into your project.

Comment: This is the best answer.  You have to netbeansify, eclipsify, etc after you do a play deps.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following dependency in your conf/dependencies.yml

```
require:
- play -> secure
```

Then, use the commands to install secure module

```
play dpes
```

If you use eclipse, remember the use the command after "play deps" command

```
play ec
```

This command will make the module visible in your eclipse